# FragmentPagerAdapter override getItem() method clash

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

In  order to implement sliding tabs in Android, i am following this guide: [Google Play Style Tabs using TabLayout](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout)

At the point of implement the [FragmentPageAdapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#implement-fragmentpageradapter) i am having a problem whith the "getItem()" method which is supossed to return the fragment with the associated position, in this case "PageFragment.newinstance(position + 1)". Being PageFragment a generic Fragment.
The problem itself is:

> 'getItem(int)' in 'com.myProject.SampleFragmentPagerAdapter' clashed
>   with 'getItem(int)' in 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter';
>   attempting to use incompatible return types

Can someone figure out where the problem is?

I have attached the SampleFragmentPagerAdapter of the guide for faster checks:

```
    public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
    private Context context;

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: got some issue need your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149039/viewpager-recyclerview-issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved, the problem was that `SampleFragmentPagerAdapter` class uses `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

I was using, `android.app.Fragment` in `PageFragment` class.

That resulted in getItem method of SampleFragmentPagerAdapter having a clash between types because of diferent libraries.

Solution? Change the import line from

```
android.app.Fragment
```

to

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragmentin PageFragment Class.
```